# Can the where-condition in this LINQ-query be optimized?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have this LINQ-query:

```
            bool? a, b, c;

            from i in _ctx.SomeEntitySet

            where
                (a == null ? true : i.IsA == a) &&
                (b == null ? true : i.IsB == b) &&
                (c == null ? true : i.IsC == c)

            select i;
```

I only want to take the condition `IsX == x` into consideration if `x != null`.

Brainfreeze, please help me out...

Comment: In general, `x == a ? true : x == b` is the same as `x == a || x == b`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
where (a == null || i.IsA == a) &&
      (b == null || i.IsB == b) &&
      (c == null || i.IsC == c)
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure it's any more efficient, but it reads better:

```
        bool? a, b, c;

        from i in _ctx.SomeEntitySet

        where
            (a == null || i.IsA == a) &&
            (b == null || i.IsB == b) &&
            (c == null || i.IsC == c)

        select i;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the version that you have most clearly expresses the intention. I would not change it.

Alternatives:

```
a == null || i.IsA == a;

!a.HasValue || i.IsA == a;

i.IsA == (a ?? i.IsA);
```

None of these is clearer to me, however. Don't focus on efficiency, focus on readability and expressiveness.

Comment: personally I think (a == null || i.IsA == a) is more readable than (a == null ? true : i.IsA == a)

Comment: Perhaps it's more readable because it's shorter but I don't think it most clearly expresses the intent of the code. Of course, this is rather subjective.